# How can I create and insert data into a table with a special name?

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I'm trying to use the jackcess library to create a database and import data into it. The problem I have found is that if I create a table named "type", which is a reserved word for jackcess, then I can not import data into this table using the ImportBuilder. A new table is generated with the prefix "x" (the new table will be named "xtype").

I also have tried to create the table with another name, import data and the rename to reserved name. But I wasn't able to find any method to rename tables.

The table has to be named "type".

What should I do?

Comment: If it's a reserved name, you can't name the table "Type".  It's as simple as that.

Comment: The funny thing is I can, but I can not import data into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackcess does appear reluctant to import a text file directly into a new table named `type`, but the following code seems to do the trick:

```java
// open existing database
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(
        "C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/foo.accdb"));

String tempTableName = "TemporaryNameForTable";

// import CSV file into new table with temporary name
ImportUtil.Builder ib = new ImportUtil.Builder(db);
ib.setTableName(tempTableName);
ib.importFile(new File("C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/foo.csv"));

// rename the new table
Table mso = db.getSystemTable("MSysObjects");
Row r = CursorBuilder.findRow(mso,
        Collections.singletonMap("Name", tempTableName));
r.put("Name", "type");  // new name is "type"
mso.updateRow(r);
db.close();
```

Comment: That is perfect. I was trying to find some setName method for the table object and didn't realize that you can rename tables that way. Thanks a lot!